# Intercept ctrl+a in GTK sharp Search Entry

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a GTK Sharp *SearchEntry* and I want to call a function when `ctrl + a` is pressed.

I have tried adding an event handler to the `KeyPressEvent` event but it doesn't receive a callback when `ctrl + a` is pressed.

I also tried overriding the `OnKeyPressEvent` function. It receives other `ctrl + key` events like this;

```
if (evnt.State == ModifierType.ControlMask && evnt.Key == Key.o)
{
     //handle ctrl + o
}
```

But this doesn't work for `ctrl + a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the *before* decoration.

```
[GLib.ConnectBefore]
private void OnKeyPressEvent(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs args)
{
    if ( evnt.State == ModifierType.ControlMask
      && evnt.Key == Key.a )
    {
        // handle ctrl + a
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.